# Terraform Prevent Destroy

Tags: azure-virtual-machine, terraform-provider-azure

I am working on creating multiple Azure VMs through terraform.
I earlier created 4 VMs with count variable successfully. Now I need to add additional 2 VMs. When I give the extra count of 2 VMs. It tries to destroy existing 4 Vms as well to create total VMs of 6. So I gave Prevent_destroy as true so that earlier 4 VMs will not be destroyed but new 2 VMs will be created. but with prevent_destroy also it gives error that Instance needs to be destroyed, this is not a desirable behavior as destroying existing 4 VMs is not expected as users are working on them I just need 2 new VMs using same script.

Comment: can you please provide the output that shows destroy for at least one vm and please provide the code you are using

Comment: If the answer was helpful, Please [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), so that others who encounter the same issue can find this solution and fix their problem.

Answer (score 0):

I tried using ******`terraform-azurerm`*** latest provider version*** ***`v2.93.0`*** with ***latest terraform version*** ***`v0.1.13`*** with the below code and it works as expected :

***I tested it by creating 2 vm's first and then added another one by changing the count value as 3 .***

```
provider "azurerm" {
  features{}
}

data "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "ansumantest"
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "example" {
  name                = "example-network"
  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "example" {
  name                 = "internal"
  resource_group_name  = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.example.name
  address_prefixes     = ["10.0.2.0/24"]
}
resource "azurerm_public_ip" "example" {
  count = 3
  name                = "vm-public-ip${count.index}"
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  allocation_method   = "Dynamic"
}

resource "azurerm_network_interface" "example" {
  count = 3
  name                = "example-nic-${count.index}"
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name

  ip_configuration {
    name                          = "internal"
    subnet_id                     = azurerm_subnet.example.id
    public_ip_address_id = "${element(azurerm_public_ip.example.*.id, count.index)}"
    private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_ssh_public_key" "example" {
  name                = "ansuman-sshkey"
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  public_key          = file("~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub")
}

resource "azurerm_linux_virtual_machine" "example" {
  count = 3
  name                = "example-machine-${count.index}"
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  size                = "Standard_F2"
  admin_username      = "adminuser"
  admin_password      = "Password@1234"
  disable_password_authentication = true
  network_interface_ids = ["${element(azurerm_network_interface.example.*.id, count.index)}"]

  admin_ssh_key {
    username   = "adminuser"
    public_key = azurerm_ssh_public_key.example.public_key
  }

  os_disk {
    caching              = "ReadWrite"
    storage_account_type = "Standard_LRS"
  }

  source_image_reference {
    publisher = "Canonical"
    offer     = "UbuntuServer"
    sku       = "16.04-LTS"
    version   = "latest"
  }
}
```

***Output:***

[image]

***After changing count from 2 to 3:***

[image]